# Using Animated.Flatlist and Animated.ScrollView to animate an Animated.View is not smooth

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist, react-animated

I am would like to make an animated header.

1. I Created an animated component of FlatList,
2. Used the `onScroll` function to update the animated value.
3. Placed a view (Animated.View) as the header above the animated FlatList using position absolute.
4. Finally, interpolate the animated value to change the view (Animated.View) using transform properties.

The animation works fine, but the animation is not smooth at all.

I [saw this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14037) of how using `scrollEventThrottle` helps the smoothness. So I thought using FlatList would be smooth but it's not. If your scroll while pressing, it's smooth. But if you scroll and leave the finger, it's jumpy ( I don't know how to describe it. Sorry). The scrolling is smooth but the animated view (Header) animation is not smooth at all.

**Environment**

- react: 16.0.0-alpha.12,
- react-native: ^0.47.0,
- node: v7.7.3
- npm: 4.1.2
- yarn: 0.21.3

**Target Platform:** iOS and Android

**Build tools:** expo

[Link to snack demo](https://snack.expo.io/HySw-PtY-)

```js
export default class AnimatedHeader extends React.Component {
 state = {
  animatedValue: new Animated.Value(0),
 };
 
 _renderItem = ({item}) => {
  return (
   <View style={styles.nonsenseItem}>
    <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item}</Text>
   </View>
  )
 };
 
 render() {
  let scaleY = this.state.animatedValue.interpolate({
   inputRange: [0, 180],
   outputRange: [1, 0.5],
   extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });
  
  let translateY = this.state.animatedValue.interpolate({
   inputRange: [0, 180],
   outputRange: [0, -100],
   extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });
  
  return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
    <AnimatedFlatList
     contentContainerStyle={{marginTop: 200}}
     scrollEventThrottle={16} // <-- Use 1 here to make sure no events are ever missed
     onScroll={Animated.event(
      [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: this.state.animatedValue}}}],
      {useNativeDriver: true} // <-- Add this
     )}
     data={data}
     renderItem={this._renderItem}
     keyExtractor={(item, i) => i}/>
    <Animated.View style={[styles.headerWrapper, {transform: [{scaleY}, {translateY}]}]}/>
   </View>
  )
 }
}
```

**Update**

So, I tried to implement the same functionality using ScrollView. However, I think, its event worse using ScrollView when compared to FlatList.

[Here is the expo snack demo: Animated ScrollView Header](https://snack.expo.io/BJYG3iFFZ)

I think I need to mention how I got here at the first place. So, I tried to implement this by a very nice [tutorial in Medium](https://medium.com/appandflow/react-native-scrollview-animated-header-10a18cb9469e), and also by watching this [awesome youtube react conf viedo by Brent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZCriZRuaow). However, the exact code used on youtube video has the same effect. Also, on the Medium tutorial, the author has given a Link to his [expo Animated header link](https://exp.host/@janic/scrollable-header), which works very smoothly. But the same code doesn't work smoothly when I copy paste the code. So, I think the problem is with the react or react native version. I will update if I have any new update. Thank you.

Comment: Interesting, it seems pretty smooth (as in native smooth) to me, both when holding down and swiping. I'm on an iPhone 7 running 10.3.3...what hardware are you on? The preview has behaviour as you describe, mind you, but the main thing is how it is on real hardware...

Comment: Interesting indeed... can confirm this problem occurs when running the attached Snack on Samsung S8 Android device, and only when applying momentum after a swipe, not when tracking with finger. Seems like a potential issue with how the backing native scroll view issues events.

Comment: Possibly worth noting that `scrollEventThrottle` is not implemented on Android, so tweaking that parameter does nothing.

Comment: Further, it appears that the Animated.event `useNativeDriver` optimization wouldn't do anything when using with FlatList, since the underlying VirtualizedList implementation wraps it and calls it manually on every event on the JS side, which may explain the deoptimization compared to standard ListView/ScrollView... https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/2ceed954904e4097f37eb99655808452d3e28997/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L994-L997

Comment: Note (mostly to self at this point :), seems to happen with just Animated.ScrollView. Interestingly, in this example using `useNativeDriver: false` actually yields better perf on my S8: https://snack.expo.io/HJYtCsFtb

Comment: @jevakallio Yes, I also just updated my question with the same issue. You could check the updated question. I think the issue is with the react native version. So, I have also changed the title of the question.

Comment: @sinewave440hz Yes, I am on Samsung galaxy S7 (android).

Comment: Seems like the same perf issue happening in all supported Expo versions 14.0-20.0 (RN 0.42-0.47).

Comment: @jevakallio Could you please try the expo link of the Medium author? It's working fine on my android phone. Would love to hear your input.

Comment: Yeah, Janic's example works well for me! Funnily, I can't tell why it works better than your example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153560/discussion-between-kakar-and-jevakallio).

Comment: @jevakallio Yes! I have also (posted an issue in github)[https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15769] regarding this issue. Hopefully some of the core developers will have some answers. Anyways I will keep on updating if I find anything. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There has been a regression in React Native 0.46 which, fortunately, has been fixed in 0.48.2** (see [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15769) and [this PR](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/15761)). That's why you're having the issue with recent Expo versions. I've had this problem with custom parallax images, and this was solved by building a custom binary with RN 0.48.3.

Your code is fine, even though I would recommend setting `scrollEventThrottle` to `1` as this really helps smoothing things out on iOS.

Comment: Yes, I posted that issue. Did you confirm that issue in your android device?

Comment: Absolutely, I've had this issue on Android and RN 0.48.3 solved it. Are you still experiencing it?

Comment: No, actually I am using expo and not the `react native init`. And expo's latest SDK still uses the RN 0.47 version so I can't say anything now.

Comment: I've just tried your initial example in the latest version of Expo (`1.2.0`, based on RN `0.48`), and everything looks pretty smooth to me. Seems like the regression has been properly fixed in `0.48.2`.